# Reg function pointer

Tags: c++, c

I have one clarification

What is the difference between calling a function through function pointer and calling a function directly by name ?

Anybody help me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in the actual call. Parameters are passed the same way, the function runs the same way, and the return value comes back the same way.

The only difference is that you can make the function pointer point somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference except that a compiler/linker calculates exactly what address to transfer control of the program to when you call a function by name and hardcodes that value into the code, whereas with function pointers, the computer must use the pointer to calculate where to transfer control to at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

No difference (except that calling by name will always call the same function, and pointer can be changed to point to different functions).

Answer (score 0):

While the direct use of function pointers does not have any cost, you should bear in mind that function pointers aren't compile time constants, so it maybe has a cost to read them. So if you have a function pointer inside a class and use that to emulate polymorphic behavior, you won't get any speedup at all.